# Deleting a specific channel discord.js v.13

Tags: discord, discord.js, ticket-system

I'm trying to script a Ticket System. I can create my channel but unfortunately not delete it with a command. My Bot has all the permissions that are needed.

My Ticket System:

```js
case 'ticket':
        case 'Ticket':

            var guild = client.guilds.cache.get('877207087521369512')
            guild.channels.create(message.author.username + '-ticket', {
                type: 'text',
                topic:  message.author.id + '-ticket',
                parent: '896402801254446046',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    {
                     id: message.author.id,
                     allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'EMBED_LINKS', 'ATTACH_FILES'],
                    },
                    {
                     id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                     deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    },
                {
                     id: "8775700854001735",
                     allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    },
                   ],
                  })

            let created = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Ticket-System")
            .setDescription("You're ticket is created")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor("GREY")
            
            
            message.channel.send({embeds: [created]});
            
            let newchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `${message.author.username}-ticket`);
            message.guild.channels.cache.get(`${newchannel}`)
```

My code for deleting a channel:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'close')) {
  message.channel.delete()
}
```

Comment: What happens instead? Is there an error? Does nothing happen? This is valid code which should delete the channel

Comment: I don't get any error codes or anything it just doesn't work

Comment: Is there any code above that?

Comment: The ticket system and other commands from my bot

Comment: Are there any `return` statements above it?

Comment: Yeah in a few codes theres a `return` function

Comment: So i deleted all my code and just left the Ticket System, no `return` code or anything and it just doesn't work